# Video Stitching from multiple cameras

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-capture

I wanted to stitch a video from multiple cameras. While stitching I wanted to switch view from one camera to another. Is it possible to do it in OpenCv?

For example I have 3 video paths(videos having same duration) and wanted to create a single video summary by switching between the videos. To start with I have created 3 video capture objects as shown below.

```
cap0=cv2.VideoCapture(path1)
cap1=cv2.VideoCapture(path2)
cap2=cv2.VideoCapture(path3)
```

similary, I also created

```
ret,frame0=cap0.read()
ret,frame1=cap1.read()
ret,frame3=cap2.read()
```

Now initially I will have frames from that are read by cap0 and passed into VideoWriter object. After some time I wanted to insert frames that are read from path2 from the time where I switched from path 1. like If I wrote frames till 3 sec from path 1,I wanted to insert frames of path 2 from the 4 sec till 6 sec

Now if I switch back again to path1 then I wanted to insert frames from the 7 sec by skipping the frames of path1 from 4sec to 6 sec.

Is there any way doing this like may be skipping the frames or any other alternative

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this by first finding the fps of your videos using

```
int fps = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture1, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
```

now calculate the number of frames you want to capture,

```
numberOfFrames = fps*time
```

this time is the time for which you want to capture one video.Thus calculate starting and end frame for each videostream. Then capture these frames as images in Mat and use VideoWriter to write

Comment: Inorder to convert them to images is it necessary to calculate the index or position to until when should I convert,And If i return back is there a way to keep track of the skipped frames like for the scenario mentioned in the above question

Comment: Yes it is necessary to calculate position if u want to work on images. yes you can keep track of skipped frames. Easiest way, is to store images in vector<Mat> then use them when required.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have written while stitching so I assume you want to make a sort of gui and see the results of switching at different time, otherwise Garvita Tiwari answer's seems to be correct.

One way of doing is to use createTrackbar of a variable(say) vid_no with its value ranging from 0 to num_Cams - 1.Now u can simply use if else depending upon the value of variable vid_no to capture  frames from the desired video.
Format for using Trackbar in OpenCv

```
createTrackbar("select_Video", "control", &vid_no, num_Cams - 1);
```